# how to assign or print out value for a vector in a structure?

Tags: c++, vector, structure

Hey I have a structure

```
typedef struct CLUSTERINFO{
 unsigned cluster;
 vector <string> scopids;
 }clusterinfo;
```

It looks like i have some issues to assign the value in to the vector scopids and then print them out

```
multimap<unsigned, clusterinfo> classinfomap;
clusterinfo clinfo;
string id_req;
 //vector<unsigned> cluster_req_list and clustersipinfomap are some known from previous modules
for (ib=cluster_req_list.begin(); ib !=cluster_req_list.end(); ib++)
     {
      if(clustersipinfomap.count(*ib)>0)
   {        
        cout<<count1<<"\t"<<*ib<<"\t"; 
    clinfo.cluster= *ib;
    std::pair<multimap<unsigned,sipinfo>::iterator, multimap<unsigned,sipinfo>::iterator> ret;
    set<string>id_req_list;
    id_req_list.clear();
    ret=clustersipinfomap.equal_range(*ib);
    //obtain the id_req_list 
    for (multimap<unsigned, sipinfo>:: iterator ic=ret.first; ic!=ret.second; ++ic)
    {
         string id_tmp=ic->second.id;
        id_req_list.insert(id_tmp);
         *****(clinfo.scopids).push_back(id_tmp);   //i got sth wrong here


    }
```

again sth is wrong for printing out the vector in the structure;

```
 multimap<unsigned, clusterinfo>::iterator ip;
   for(ip= classinfomap.begin(); ip!=classinfomap.end(); ip ++)
   {
         cout<<ip->first <<"\t"<< ip->second.cluster<<endl;
        for (unsigned it=0; it< (ip->second.scopids).size(); it++)
        {
            count<< (ip->second.scopids)[it] << endl;
        }

   }
```

Comment: Please define "some issues" and "wrong"

Comment: Why don't you drop all the irrelevant code and just try to call `insert` on a simple vector?

Comment: use push_back for vector and insert for set

Comment: the report message was  error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::count << ip.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = std::pair<const unsigned int, CLUSTERINFO>]()->std::pair<const unsigned int, CLUSTERINFO>::second.CLUSTERINFO::scopids.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >](((long unsigned int)it))'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to "assign" a value to a vector in a structure: you probably want to add an element to the vector, which you can achieve with `std::vector::push_back`:

```
struct Foo
{
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
};

Foo f;
std::string s("Hello, World!";
f.vec.push_back(s);
```

How to print out contents of the vector?

C++11

```
for (const auto& e : f.vec)
  std::cout << e << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

C++03

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = f.vec.begin(); it != f.vec.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << *it << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```